# Sequelize: Can't do update on column UpdatedAt

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've an express apps that use Sequelize as ORM. Basically, columns createdAt and updatedAt auto-generated by Sequelize.
Every time I do update data in a row except column updatedAt, the column updatedAt will be updated based on current datetime.
But when I'm trying to update the column updatedAt, it didn't update the value of column `updatedAt.`
I've several way based on docs and another issue in so, like:

```
value.set('createdAt', new Date());
   value.save().then(value1 => {
            console.log('UpdatedAt has been updated');
            next();
   }
)
```

and

```
    Token.update(
    {
        updatedAt: new Date
    },
    {
        where: {
            token_id: token
        }
    }
).then(value1 => {
        console.log('Token UpdatedAt has been updated');
    }
)
```

But non of both work.

Anyone know why? and how to fix that. Thankyou.

Comment: Hmmm... In the first example, you're trying to update `createdAt` column instead of `updatedAt`, in the second - there is a typo `updatedAt: new Date` should be `updatedAt: new Date()`.

Answer (score 2):

The short and simple way for this is :

```
Token.changed('updatedAt', true); // <--- This will update the updatedAt field
```

Comment: I didn't find method `changed` in sequelize

Comment: @Blackjack, read this : https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-changed, make sure that is model